# A mySQL query for returning customers that make multiple purchases and the specific time of the 5th purchase

Tags: mysql, database

"loyal" customers are considered loyal if they have purchased at least 5 times.
I am trying to build an SQL query which returns only "loyal" customers along with the day on
which they become "loyal" customers (the day of their 5th transaction).

| user_id | purchase_ts |
| --- | --- |
| f594fsae | 2021-07-21 |
| ........ | ............ |

Ideally the desired output would be as follows

| loyal_user_id | Loyal_Moment |
| --- | --- |
| f594fsae | 2021-07-29 |
| .............. | ............ |

I tried creating a new table as follows:

```
SELECT user_id, purchase_ts
    FROM Customers
    WHERE user_id IN (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM Customers
        GROUP BY user_id
        HAVING COUNT (user_id) >=5
)
```

But I am having trouble, any suggestions?

Comment: What trouble do you have ? Isn't the result as expected ? What `MySQL` version are you using ? Please add some data and expected result

Comment: my main trouble is trying to figure out how to query the time stamp for the 5th transaction for each customer

Answer (score 0):

On `MySQL 8` you could use:

```
with cte as
            ( select   *, 
                       row_number() over (partition by user_id order by purchase_ts asc) row_num
             from accounts
            ) 
select user_id,purchase_ts
from cte
where row_num >=5;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> user_id       purchase_ts
> f594fsae       2021-07-25
> f632fsae       2021-07-25
> ```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3qhqCyjZmR7dxgcFTv9oyT/1)

Comment: Im new to Mysql so I dont really understand what you did here, could you possibly do a brief explanation if you have the time?

Comment: @SPINCHAINZ  with the introduction of windows function it is much easier to order the data. row_number assigns a sequential number to each row in the result set. The first number begins with one. I like the explanation on [this link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) of the row_number. Check and let me know if you have questions

Comment: so you used the row number function to basically show the user id that made 5 or more purchases and the associated time stamp for the 5th purchase?

Comment: Yes, it will return the ID and corresponding BUY_ts of each user which has made 5 or more  purchases

Comment: @SPINCHAINZ you have an example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xsmqxXuT1xurBhGTvMPzEK/0 . You can check the first query that select * from cte to see the values of row_number. The second query I filter the results

Comment: sorry if im being a newb, but I tried your solution and it didn't quite work for me :(

Comment: @SPINCHAINZ you should edit the question and add data examples and expected result. I can't  know  for sure without data

Comment: Hi Ergest, I just edited the question

Comment: @SPINCHAINZ please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question and update with data in text format

Comment: I tried adding the tables, in edit view it looked fine now its weird? haha

Comment: @SPINCHAINZ I updated the answer adding  a demo. It works fine. Keep in mind that you must have MySQL 8+ version

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL introduced the support of subquery a long time ago, we have been using its techniques in some MySQL-version-nonspecific scenarios. In this case, we can use a correlated subquery to get exactly the fifth purchase_ts by using the LIMIT [OFFSET] clause. The WHERE clause is used to exclude those purchase_id which doesn't have a fifth purchase_ts.

```
select distinct user_Id, 
(select purchase_ts from purchase where user_id=p.user_id order by purchase_ts limit 4,1) as loyal_time 
from purchase p 
where (select purchase_ts from purchase where user_id=p.user_id order by purchase_ts limit 4,1) is not null;
```

Comment: Just like you to know, alias defined in the SELECT clause can not be used in the WHERE clause. But if we feel lazy, we can resort to an unconventional way of using HAVING clause instead. That is to say, in the above statement , we can use `HAVING loyal_time is not null` instead. This is not recommended though in production workplace.